# How do you explain this paradox in probability? A slight change in conditions doubles the probability!

Tags: probability, combinatorics, paradoxes

The paradox is simple to explain but it really confuses me.
Suppose *X* is the weight of a mango from a very large batch of mangoes. Let's say *X* is normally distributed with mean $= 300$g, so the probability of a randomly picked mango weighing less than $300$g is $1/2$.

If you pick two mangoes at random, the probablity that both of them weigh less than 300g is $\frac{1}{2}×\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$.

However, if you change the condition by a little and ask: If two mangoes are picked again at random, what is the probability that one weighs less than 300g and the other weighs less than 299.9999g? You have to consider the two possible orders and apply permutation. The answer would be $2×\frac{1}{2}×(\frac{1}{2} - \text{a teeny tiny amount})$ which is about $\frac{1}{2}$, almost double of $\frac{1}{4}$!

What I don't understand is that there seem to be very little difference between the two situations yet there is a huge disparity in the results. Is there something very significant about that slight change of $0.0001$g? Or does this just mean that such questions that you get from school math papers are meaningless in practice (eg. Probability of picking $2$ white balls and $1$ black ball from $20$ white and $30$ black balls)?

Thanks for any help to clarify this paradoxical situation.

Comment: you are neglecting the overlap. The probability that *both* mangoes weigh less than $299.9999$ is $\frac 14$ and you doubled counted that case.

Comment: What do you mean by doubling counting? So you are saying that the correct answer to the second situation should be 1/4? Thanks. @lulu

Comment: Of course it should be $\frac 14$...as you (correctly) remark, it's the same as the original problem (I'm ignoring the small probability of weighing between $299.9999$ and $300$, that changes the numbers in a very, very small way).

Comment: Double counting means what it sounds like, you are counting those events twice.  As a general matter, given two events in a probability space, $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.  You disregarded that last term.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your explanation. So, to be crystal clear, the question is asking for $P((X_1<300 \cap X_2<299.9999) \cup (X_1<299.9999 \cap X_2<300))$ and when you apply this identity, the answer should be  $P(X_1<300 \cap X_2<299.9999) + P(X_1<299.9999 \cap X_2<300) - P(X_1<299.9999\cap X_2<299.9999)$. Does this sound right? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: OK thank you so much!